# Using cakephp3, how to custom method and action in route

Tags: php, routes, cakephp-3.0

I know POST method is pointing to `add()` in a controller as default in `cakephp3`. Is it possible to custom that and point POST method to `index()`? Something like below:

```
Router::connect(
    '/test',
    array(
        'controller' => 'Test',
        'action' => 'index',
        '[method]' => 'POST'
    )
);
```

Comment: By default, routes do match all HTTP methods, unless you are using [**resource routing**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#restful-routing) or explicitly [**define specific methods**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#matching-specific-http-methods). If you cannot POST to your test route, then you may have a different problem, which in order to be solvable, will require more information about the routes that exist in your application.

Comment: Without routing you can do this by redirecting to index action from test by checking like if($this->request->is(['POST'])) { $this->redirect(['action' => 'index'])}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ndm who made a very clear solution for my question.

One of my issue is that I have `$routes->resources('Test');` which will disable @ndm's solutions. So first of all, I commented out the line `$routes->resources('Test');`.

Because of I'm not working on a solid project which is a temporary project for a narrowed purpose, so below code is working perfectly for me now.

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->setExtensions(['json']);
//    $routes->resources('Test');

    $routes->post(
        '/test',
        ['controller' => 'Test', 'action' => 'add']
    );
});
```